# CMake error when building rclcpp

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got some errors when building rclcpp using `colcon build`. The error message is shown below. Any idea where the problem is? I had sourced ${ROS_WS}/install/setup.bash before running `colcon build`.

```
 root@48fcb45ebd09:/opt/ros_ws# cat log/latest_build/rclcpp/stderr.log
CMake Error at test/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findtest_msgs.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "test_msgs", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "test_msgs" with
  any of the following names:

    test_msgsConfig.cmake
    test_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "test_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "test_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "test_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371790/cmake-error-when-building-rclcpp/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2021-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-14**:
Could you please close either #q371789 or this one?

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2021-02-14**:
Sorry for the mishap. I edited the question but got a duplicate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems things start to work if I do `rosdep install -y --from-paths src`. I am still a bit surprised that `colcon build` itself does not take care of dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) with karma: 186 on 2021-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-14**:
Colcon builds packages.

It does not detect, resolve nor download dependencies.

The error you show is a CMake error, as it's CMake which checks whether required dependencies are present (as long as the developer/maintainer has written a proper `CMakeLists.txt` that is).

Personally I quite like the separation of concerns. Build tools which try to do everything can be rather annoying.

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2021-02-15**:
Separation of concerns makes sense to me. Thanks.